# jQuery Change Value based on Value

Tags: jquery

Can you change the value of an input field based on the original value?

```
<input type="checkbox" value="fooBar1" class="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" value="fooBar2" class="checkbox" />
```

Was trying something like this ...

```
if ($('.checkbox').val() == 'fooBar1') {
   $(this).val('1');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
$(".checkbox[value=fooBar1]").val(1);
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm, forgot you could use the value attribute as the selector.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($("input.checkbox").attr("value") == "fooBar1") {
   $(this).attr("value","NEW VALUE");
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but trying to do this same thing to more than one element ... like so, http://jsfiddle.net/8g9vP/5/

Comment: I stripped down some stuff to make it simpler, idk what exactly you wanted to do but here's what i got: http://jsfiddle.net/8g9vP/7/